# HTML Input value not displaying after first comma when reading python string

Tags: python, html, string, flask, input

So, i have a Flask App where the user can adjust some values via an input. The default value of the input will not display correctly if it is reading a python string that is in the form of a list.

so in my main.py i define the following variable:

```
python_string_list = "1,2,3,4"
```

in my page.html i have:

```
<input type="text" name="MJ" id="MJ" value={{python_string_list}}>
```

but the default value that appears in the input box on the html page is just: 1,

if, however i use:

```
<input type="text" name="MJ" id="MJ" value="1,2,3,4">
```

the whole list appears, as expected.

Not sure what im doing wrong but would really appreciate some help.

Edit:
Seems the error cant be replicated so i will add the full code. Not sure if it makes a difference but my input box is in a table:

```
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table align-items-center table-flush">
        <thead class="thead-light">
            <tr>
                <th class="border-bottom" scope="col"> Title </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr class "fw-bolder text-gray-500">
                <input type="text" name="MJ" id="MJ" value={{python_string_list}}>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: How do you invoke the `render_template` method?

Comment: It is working fine to me

Comment: its not, that. I pass the variable through it. If i change python_string_list to = 'hello'. it works.  I think its something to do with the comma. Just tried 'hello, hello...' and only 'hello,' appears

Comment: the input is inside a table, not sure why that'd make a difference though

Comment: It seems that I can't duplicate the error, here is my code:
Python

```@app.route("/anothertest")
def anothertest():
  python_string_list = "1,2,3,4"
  return render_template("helping.html", python_string_list = python_string_list)
```


HTML

```<input type="text" name="MJ" id="MJ" value={{python_string_list}} >
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved: My string list had spaces and shouldn't have done